# "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" removes leading zeroes on scan

Tags: android, zxing

Hey so currently my code implements the "com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN" intent method to scan barcodes into my application like so

```
public void scanBarCode(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");  

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_BARCODE);

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Start scanning Barcode", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
```

however, upon testing, I've noticed that the barcode scanner removes the leading zeroes from the scan. So any barcode with 0XXXXXXXX will only be read in my app as XXXXXXXXX. Is there anyway to see why this is  happeneing? (Maybe barcode scanner is treating it as an int?) and how I can go about keeping it from truncating future scans?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[barcode]` and `[scanner]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[barcode-scanner]` tag.  Tags are not keywords, so stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (barcode, scanner, leading, zero) won't help categorize it.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0):

If your barcode is UPC_A, UPC_E, EAN_13, EAN_8, or RSS_14 it should be working. If you need to support CODE_39, CODE_93, CODE_128, or ITF barcode formats, try setting your Intent extra "SCAN_MODE" value to "ONE_D_MODE" and see if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DecimalFormat` class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html.

```
System.out.println(  new DecimalFormat("000000000").format("000000001")  );
```

This pattern will require a 9 digit integer, and since a 0 is used instead of a # it will retain the 0